# What is Atiratra or Athirathram Yagna's?

Tags: vedas, scripture, rituals, yajna

While reading about various Yagnas which were performed during vaidic times , I came across this "Athirathram or Atiratra " Yagna's.

So my questions are - :

**1) What is exactly these "Athirathram or Atiratra" Yagna?**

**2) In  Which scripture these Yagna's and it's procedure is mentioned ?**

**3) What is the purpose of some these Yagna?**

Comment: Atiratra is one of the seven categories of Soma Yagnas.  Atiratra gets its name from the fact that it is performed for one day and one night, as opposed to other Yagnas which are just performed in the daytime.  In any case, there are many different Yagnas that fall into the category of Atiratra.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Athirathram or Atiratra** is one of the seven categories of Soma Yagnas.[Athirathram or Atiratra](http://www.brahminvoice.org/2011/04/01/athirathram-athirathra-homam-2011/) refers to “building up of the fireplace and performed overnight”. Seventeen priests are required for performing the ‘Agni’. The course of time is 12 days. the piling of the altar of Agni is a [Srauta](http://www.religious-information.com/srauta-religion.html) ritual of Vedic religion.
It is also [the world’s oldest surviving ritual.](http://athirathram-2012.blogspot.in/2012_04_01_archive.html) 
Its mantras and theological explanations in the Brahmana texts are **mentioned  in the Yajurveda Samhitas (Taittiriya, Kathaka; Vajasaneya).** The practice of this ritual was generally discontinued from late vaidic period.

> **A brief Part of Procedure -:** 
>   The First day begins with the Yajamana and his priests entering the ritual enclosure carrying three sacred fires in pots. The main ritual vessel is prepared from clay. A symbolic animal sacrifice would be performed for Vayu. After selection of five chief priests fire is produced by friction. This is followed by tying a turban around the head of Yajamana. He is protected by a golden breast plate, is given a staff and closes his fists and deprived of speaking (except for recitations), from bathing etc. The Yajamana picks up the main ritual vessel filled with fire, and takes three steps with it. brief Part of Procedure -:  The First day begins with the Yajamana
>   and his priests entering the ritual enclosure carrying three sacred
>   fires in pots. The main ritual vessel is prepared from clay. A
>   symbolic animal sacrifice would be performed for Vayu. After selection
>   of five chief priests fire is produced by friction. This is followed
>   by tying a turban around the head of Yajamana. He is protected by a
>   golden breast plate, is given a staff and closes his fists and
>   deprived of speaking (except for recitations), from bathing etc. The
>   Yajamana picks up the main ritual vessel filled with fire, and takes
>   three steps with it. brief Part of Procedure -:  The First day begins
>   with the Yajamana and his priests entering the ritual enclosure
>   carrying three sacred fires in pots. The main ritual vessel is
>   prepared from clay. A symbolic animal sacrifice would be performed for
>   Vayu. After selection of five chief priests fire is produced by
>   friction. This is followed by tying a turban around the head of
>   Yajamana. He is protected by a golden breast plate, is given a staff
>   and closes his fists and deprived of speaking (except for
>   recitations), from bathing etc. The Yajamana picks up the main ritual
>   vessel filled with fire, and takes three steps with it. brief Part of
>   Procedure -:  The First day begins with the Yajamana and his priests
>   entering the ritual enclosure carrying three sacred fires in pots. The
>   main ritual vessel is prepared from clay. A symbolic animal sacrifice
>   would be performed for Vayu. After selection of five chief priests
>   fire is produced by friction. This is followed by tying a turban
>   around the head of Yajamana. He is protected by a golden breast plate,
>   is given a staff and closes his fists and deprived of speaking (except
>   for recitations), from bathing etc. The Yajamana picks up the main
>   ritual vessel filled with fire, and takes three steps with it.

Purpose -:
**The ritual invokes Vedic mantras to usher Universal harmony, the welfare and well-being of all living beings on Earth and elsewhere in the Universe.**

Image taken from  [Here](http://www.athirathram.org/rituals.htm)